# SUM by two different GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I'm getting the wrong result from my report. Maybe i'm missing something simple.

The report is an inline table-valued-function that should count goods movement in our shop and how often these spareparts are claimed(replaced in a repair).

The problem: different spareparts in the shop-table(lets call it `SP`) can be linked to the same sparepart in the "repair-table"(`TSP`). I need the goods movement of every sparepart in `SP` and the claim-count of every **distinct** sparepart in `TSP`.

This is a very simplified excerpt of the relevant part:

```
create table #tsp(id int, name varchar(20),claimed int);
create table #sp(id int, name varchar(20),fiTsp int,ordered int);

insert into #tsp values(1,'1235-6044',300);
insert into #tsp values(2,'1234-5678',400);

insert into #sp values(1,'1235-6044',1,30);
insert into #sp values(2,'1235-6044',1,40);
insert into #sp values(3,'1235-6044',1,50);
insert into #sp values(4,'1234-5678',2,60);

WITH cte AS(
    select tsp.id As TspID,tsp.name as TspName,tsp.claimed As Claimed
    ,sp.id As SpID,sp.name As SpName,sp.ordered As Ordered
    from #sp sp inner join #tsp tsp
    on sp.fiTsp=tsp.id
)
SELECT TspName, SUM(Claimed) As Claimed, Sum(Ordered) As Ordered
FROM cte
Group By TspName

drop table #tsp;
drop table #sp;
```

Result:

```
TspName       Claimed   Ordered
1234-5678       400       60
1235-6044       900       120
```

The `Ordered`-count is correct but the `Claimed`-count should be 300 instead of 900 for TspName='1235-6044'.

I need to group by `Tsp.ID` for the claim-count and group by `Sp.ID` for the order-count. But how in one query?

**Edit**: Actually the TVF looks like(note that `getOrdered` and `getClaimed` are SVFs and that i'm grouping in the outer select on TSP's Category):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [Gambio].[rptReusedStatistics](
     @fromDate datetime
    ,@toDate datetime
    ,@fromInvoiceDate datetime
    ,@toInvoiceDate datetime
    ,@idClaimStatus varchar(50)
    ,@idSparePartCategories varchar(1000)
    ,@idSpareParts varchar(1000)
)

RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN(
    WITH ExclusionCat AS(
        SELECT idSparePartCategory AS ID From tabSparePartCategory
        WHERE idSparePartCategory IN(- 3, - 1, 6, 172,168)
    ), Report AS(
        SELECT Cat.SparePartCategoryName AS Category
        ,TSP.SparePartDescription AS Part
        ,TSP.SparePartName AS PartNumber
        ,SP.Inventory
        ,Gambio.getGoodsIn(SP.idSparePart,@FromDate,@ToDate) GoodsIn
        ,Gambio.getOrdered(SP.idSparePart,@FromDate,@ToDate) Ordered
        --,CASE WHEN TSP.idSparePart IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE
        --  Gambio.getClaimed(TSP.idSparePart,@FromInvoiceDate,@ToInvoiceDate,@idClaimStatus,NULL)END AS Claimed
        ,CASE WHEN TSP.idSparePart IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE
            Gambio.getClaimed(TSP.idSparePart,@FromInvoiceDate,@ToInvoiceDate,@idClaimStatus,1)END AS ClaimedReused
        ,CASE WHEN TSP.idSparePart IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE
            Gambio.getCostSaving(TSP.idSparePart,@FromInvoiceDate,@ToInvoiceDate,@idClaimStatus)END AS Costsaving
        FROM  Gambio.SparePart AS SP 
        INNER JOIN tabSparePart AS TSP ON SP.fiTabSparePart = TSP.idSparePart 
        INNER JOIN tabSparePartCategory AS Cat 
        ON Cat.idSparePartCategory=TSP.fiSparePartCategory
        WHERE Cat.idSparePartCategory NOT IN(SELECT ID FROM ExclusionCat)
        AND (@idSparePartCategories IS NULL 
            OR TSP.fiSparePartCategory IN(
                SELECT Item From dbo.Split(@idSparePartCategories,',')
            )
        )
        AND (@idSpareParts IS NULL 
            OR TSP.idSparePart IN(
                SELECT Item From dbo.Split(@idSpareParts,',')
            )
        )
    )
    SELECT Category
    --, Part
    --, PartNumber
    , SUM(Inventory)As InventoryCount
    , SUM(GoodsIn) As GoodsIn
    , SUM(Ordered) As Ordered
    --, SUM(Claimed) As Claimed
    , SUM(ClaimedReused)AS ClaimedReused
    , SUM(Costsaving) As Costsaving
    , Count(*) AS PartCount
    FROM Report
    GROUP BY Category
)
```

---

**Solution**:

Thanks to Aliostad i've solved it by first grouping and then joining(actual TVF, reduced to a minimum):

```
WITH Report AS(
        SELECT Cat.SparePartCategoryName AS Category
        ,TSP.SparePartDescription AS Part
        ,TSP.SparePartName AS PartNumber
        ,SP.Inventory
        ,SP.GoodsIn
        ,SP.Ordered
        ,Gambio.getClaimed(TSP.idSparePart,@FromInvoiceDate,@ToInvoiceDate,@idClaimStatus,1) AS ClaimedReused
        ,Gambio.getCostSaving(TSP.idSparePart,@FromInvoiceDate,@ToInvoiceDate,@idClaimStatus) AS Costsaving
        FROM  (
            SELECT GSP.fiTabSparePart 
            ,SUM(GSP.Inventory)AS Inventory
            ,SUM(Gambio.getGoodsIn(GSP.idSparePart,@FromDate,@ToDate))AS GoodsIn
            ,SUM(Gambio.getOrdered(GSP.idSparePart,@FromDate,@ToDate))AS Ordered
            FROM Gambio.SparePart GSP
            GROUP BY GSP.fiTabSparePart
        )As SP
        INNER JOIN tabSparePart TSP ON  SP.fiTabSparePart = TSP.idSparePart
        INNER JOIN tabSparePartCategory AS Cat 
        ON Cat.idSparePartCategory=TSP.fiSparePartCategory
    )
    SELECT Category
    , SUM(Inventory)As InventoryCount
    , SUM(GoodsIn) As GoodsIn
    , SUM(Ordered) As Ordered
    , SUM(ClaimedReused)AS ClaimedReused
    , SUM(Costsaving) As Costsaving
    , Count(*) AS PartCount
    FROM Report
    GROUP BY Category
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are JOINing first and then GROUPing by. You need to reverse it, GROUP BY first and then JOIN.

So here in my subquery, I group by first and then join:

```
select 
    claimed,
    ordered 
from 
     #tsp 
inner JOIN
      (select 
             fitsp, 
             SUM(ordered) as ordered 
       from 
              #sp
        group by 
              fitsp) as SUMS           
on 
     SUMS.fiTsp = id;
```

Comment: Thanks. After I've carried over your suggestion to my TVF(have a look at my edit) it works perfectly.

Comment: Great to hear it is all fixed.

Answer (score 3):

I think you just need to select Claimed and add it to the Group By in order to get what you are looking for.

```
WITH cte AS(
select tsp.id As TspID,tsp.name as TspName,tsp.claimed As Claimed
,sp.id As SpID,sp.name As SpName,sp.ordered As Ordered
from #sp sp inner join #tsp tsp
on sp.fiTsp=tsp.id )

SELECT TspName, Claimed, Sum(Ordered) As Ordered
FROM cte
Group By TspName, Claimed
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `cte` is an inner join between `tsp` and `sp`, which means that the data you're querying looks like this:

```
SpID   Ordered   TspID   TspName     Claimed
1      30        1       1235-6044   300
2      40        1       1235-6044   300
3      50        1       1235-6044   300
4      60        2       1234-5678   400
```

Notice how `TspID`, `TspName` and `Claimed` all get repeated. Grouping by `TspName` means that the data gets grouped in two groups, one for `1235-6044` and one for `1234-5678`. The first group has 3 rows on which to run the aggregate functions, the second group only one. That's why your `sum(Claimed)` will get you 300*3=900.

As Aliostad suggested, you should first group by `TspID` and do the sum of `Ordered` and then join to `tsp`.

Answer (score 1):

No need to join, just subselect:

```
create table #tsp(id int, name varchar(20),claimed int);
create table #sp(id int, name varchar(20),fiTsp int,ordered int);

insert into #tsp values(1,'1235-6044',300);
insert into #tsp values(2,'1234-5678',400);

insert into #sp values(1,'1235-6044',1,30);
insert into #sp values(2,'1235-6044',1,40);
insert into #sp values(3,'1235-6044',1,50);
insert into #sp values(4,'1234-5678',2,60);

WITH cte AS(
    select tsp.id As TspID,tsp.name as TspName,tsp.claimed As Claimed
    ,sp.id As SpID,sp.name As SpName,sp.ordered As Ordered
    from #sp sp inner join #tsp tsp
    on sp.fiTsp=tsp.id
)

SELECT id, name, SUM(claimed) as Claimed, (SELECT SUM(ordered) FROM #sp WHERE #sp.fiTsp = #tsp.id GROUP BY #sp.fiTsp) AS Ordered
FROM #tsp
GROUP BY id, name

drop table #tsp;
drop table #sp;
```

Produces:

```
id  name        Claimed Ordered 
1   1235-6044   300 120 
2   1234-5678   400 60
```

-- EDIT --

Based on the additional info, this is how I might try to split the CTE to form the data as per the example. I fully admit that Aliostad's approach may yield a cleaner query but here's an attempt (completely blind) using the subselect:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [Gambio].[rptReusedStatistics](
     @fromDate datetime
    ,@toDate datetime
    ,@fromInvoiceDate datetime
    ,@toInvoiceDate datetime
    ,@idClaimStatus varchar(50)
    ,@idSparePartCategories varchar(1000)
    ,@idSpareParts varchar(1000)
)

RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN(
    WITH ExclusionCat AS (
        SELECT idSparePartCategory AS ID From tabSparePartCategory
        WHERE idSparePartCategory IN(- 3, - 1, 6, 172,168)
    ), ReportSP AS (
        SELECT fiTabSparePart
        ,Inventory
        ,Gambio.getGoodsIn(idSparePart,@FromDate,@ToDate) GoodsIn
        ,Gambio.getOrdered(idSparePart,@FromDate,@ToDate) Ordered
        FROM  Gambio.SparePart
    ), ReportTSP AS (
        SELECT TSP.idSparePart
        ,Cat.SparePartCategoryName AS Category
        ,TSP.SparePartDescription AS Part
        ,TSP.SparePartName AS PartNumber
        ,CASE WHEN TSP.idSparePart IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE
            Gambio.getClaimed(TSP.idSparePart,@FromInvoiceDate,@ToInvoiceDate,@idClaimStatus,1)END AS ClaimedReused
        ,CASE WHEN TSP.idSparePart IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE
            Gambio.getCostSaving(TSP.idSparePart,@FromInvoiceDate,@ToInvoiceDate,@idClaimStatus)END AS Costsaving
        FROM  tabSparePart AS TSP 
        INNER JOIN tabSparePartCategory AS Cat 
        ON Cat.idSparePartCategory=TSP.fiSparePartCategory
        WHERE Cat.idSparePartCategory NOT IN(SELECT ID FROM ExclusionCat)
        AND (@idSparePartCategories IS NULL 
            OR TSP.fiSparePartCategory IN(
                SELECT Item From dbo.Split(@idSparePartCategories,',')
            )
        )
        AND (@idSpareParts IS NULL 
            OR TSP.idSparePart IN(
                SELECT Item From dbo.Split(@idSpareParts,',')
            )
        )
    )       
    SELECT Category
    --, Part
    --, PartNumber
    , (SELECT SUM(Inventory) FROM ReportSP WHERE ReportSP.fiTabSparePart = idSparePart GROUP BY fiTabSparePart) AS Inventory
    , (SELECT SUM(GoodsIn) FROM ReportSP WHERE ReportSP.fiTabSparePart = idSparePart GROUP BY fiTabSparePart) AS GoodsIn
    , (SELECT SUM(Ordered) FROM ReportSP WHERE ReportSP.fiTabSparePart = idSparePart GROUP BY fiTabSparePart) AS Ordered
    , Claimed
    , ClaimedReused
    , Costsaving
    , Count(*) AS PartCount
    FROM ReportTSP
    GROUP BY Category
)
```

Without a better understanding of the whole schema it's difficult to cover for all the eventualities but whether this works or not (I suspect PartCount will be 1 for all instances) hopefully it'll give you some fresh thoughts for alternate approaches.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't mentioned it in the question, but actually i get the order-count and claim-count by scalar-valued functions. The first takes the SP.ID and the second the TSP.ID as argument. So i need a CTE which passes all SP's to `getOrdered` and all _distinct_ TSP's to `getClaimed`. So i cannot subselect in this CTE because it's not the location where it's calculated(and actually it's not as simple). The `SUM` will be applied on the outer select that uses the CTE and groups on Categories(every TSP belongs to a category).

Comment: @TimSchmelter Are the scalar functions set in stone? As I understand the structure, the SP.id is irrelevant, you should be able to pass the TSP.id to both.

Comment: I'm afraid they are, actually the calculation is much more difficult. Neither the order-count nor the claim-count are columns in these tables but must be calculated on given timespans, statuses and a reused-flag in other fact tables. Hence i've created these scalar functions. So i've tried to encapsulate the problem with this simplified example.

Comment: The simplest option I can think of is to follow the example, create the two tables. Break your `Report` query into two queries that generates a table of SP records and a table of TSP orders, then the last stage can group as either I or Aliostad has indicated.

Comment: Thank you for your example with two queries. But finally i've managed it to implement Aliostad's approach into my TVF(see my edit) which works perfectly and is fast enough.

Comment: That's great, as I mentioned either approach worked and I would have used Aliostad's approach myself but didn't want to plagiarise his work.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
tsp.name
,max(tsp.claimed) as claimed
,sum(sp.ordered) as ordered 
from #sp sp 
inner join #tsp tsp 
on sp.fiTsp=tsp.id
GROUP BY tsp.name
```

Comment: The `MAX` will not help me since it works only on this little sample data and not on the whole query where i'm grouping on SparePartCategories(TSP belongs to a category). It's also normally correct that i need the sum on the claim-count.